# SMS text mining

Tags: nlp, sms, text-mining

I am trying to extract numeric information from set of SMSs. The regexes fail in extracting balance and credit amounts as the patterns of the SMS is not consistent throughout the industry.
We are currently making assumptions to make it work like First Amount = Credit amount
Second Amount=Balance.
This has lot of limitations and error rate is gradually increasing.
Anyone has any alternatives to regexes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for this kind of message as every operator creates its own messages. this is marketing communication... Yet, for a given operator and a given plan all replies to balance inquiry messages should be the sames (as long as they are not changed by operators marketing teams...).

Regexes are a good tool but you need to know the message forehand and create the appropriate regex patterns

Comment: That the reason I am trying to generalize my approach.I have read about NER to extract account  and numeric info . But unable to succefully implement it.